# If you do sth v. If you are to do sth

Tags: grammar

Generally speaking, what is the difference between structures like "If you [do something]" and "if you are [to do something]"? I don't see any purpose, stylistic it otherwise, to use the latter instead of the former in the sentence below. I believe I am familiar with these "formal" inversions, but I deem it irrelevant here

[image]

> 2. In more formal styles *if* can be dropped and the auxiliary verb inverted.
>
> ***Were** you to **question** me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.*
> ***Had** I **known** that he was a journalist, I would have said nothing.*

Let's step the inversion and boil the question down to this: what's the difference between these two sentences:

> If you questioned me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.
>
> If you were to question me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.

Comment: Your generalized examples don't match the examples in the quoted text.  The text is noting these two possible forms of the same sentence: "If you were to [do something]" -> "Were you to [do something]."  Are you asking about this, or about the examples you gave: "If you [do something]" -> "If you are [to do something]"?  Because that's a completely different situation.

Comment: I imagine the rest of this page makes it clear that it's talking about the *[subjunctive mood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood)*. If you use the simple present verb "are," you can't do the same trick. If you want to edit the question to ask about the difference between "If you were to ___" and "Were you to ___," the answer is that there is no difference in meaning, and in my opinion, little difference in tone. (If you're asking about the difference between "If you question me" and "if you were to question me," then there's a huge difference.)

Comment: @juhasz I'm not asking about inversions. I'm asking about the difference between "to do something" and "to be to do something" (I know what it can mean: orders, expected or scheduled events, etc.). I don't see what it adds to the sentence here

Comment: If you're asking about "you do something" versus "you are to something," you should remove the example from the book.  That example has nothing to do with "to do something" or "are to do something."  The example in the book is saying this: *there are two different ways to write the same sentence - "if you were to question me..." and "were you to question me..."*  This is a completely different situation than "you ask me a question" and "you are to ask me a question."

Comment: @juhasz ignore the inversion, it has nothing to do with my question. Inverted, but inverted, it still has a certain purpose, using "to be to do something", that evades me. That's the focus of the question

Comment: "You are to [verb]" can be understood to mean _planning to, destined to, intending to_ and the like. "John and I are to be married next year."

Comment: This is confusing. You boil down a post asking about the "are to" construction with a "were to" example. These are different. "Were to" is a hypothetical/conditional sort of construction. "Are to" is what @KateBunting discusses in her comment above. I don't think there's any difference in meaning between your final two sentences.

Comment: @cruthers but it's hypothetical/conditional without 'were' as well

Comment: Yeah, kind of, as in @FumbleFingers's example #2. That's somewhat rare and elevated and, more to the point, has a different meaning than "were to" in the subjunctive/conjunctive sense. "If you are to" sets up a prerequisite, "if you were to" sets up a consequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To be to X* means to plan/need/have to do X because something requires, compels, or forces it.

It doesn't mean X has been done yet.

It's often used as a polite but firm imperative, and used to talk about an action that an employer or law is requiring.  Hence the formal "flavor" of the construction.

> If you were to question me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.

Speaker is communicating an assumption that the person asking a question wouldn't be doing it because the speaker wanted to, but because the speaker was required to.

> Were you to question me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.

Use subjunctive mood for extra formal flavor, or this may be normal preference for BrE.

> If you questioned me about the matter, I would deny all knowledge.

No such assumption, and any idea of formality is purely because "questioning" often describes things in the context of an official or important business or legal process.

Comment: So is it the same as "if you had to [...]"?

Comment: You may consider answering my previous question and also this. Lexico includes the following sense for "to be": "Used to hypothesize about something that might happen." What does it mean? "If you were to do something" could be simply used instead of "if you did something" with no difference in meaning of style? If so, how do you know obligation is conveyed and not that? Note it's different from "used to express obligation or necessity" you were talking about in your answer which is listed earlier in the entry

Answer (score 0):

Including ***are to*** or not in OP's context changes the meaning significantly...

> 1: *If you go to university, you might learn quantum electrodynamics*
> It's possible that by going to uni, you might learn QED (but you might not go anyway)

> 2: *If you **are to** go<sup>1</sup> to university, you must learn quantum electrodynamics*
> Learning QED (now) is a *requirement* for entering uni (if you don't learn it you won't get in)

---

Note that OP's more formal "inversion" can only carry the *first* sense above...

> 3: ***Were you to** go to university, you might learn quantum electrodynamics*

---

<sup>1</sup> You might find it easier to parse the construction ***If you are to [do something]*** after considering a "non-conditional" reference to future activity: *I **am to** go to London tomorrow* *( = I **will** go...)*.

The effect of including ***are to*** in OP's context is to change the "condition" queried by ***if*** from being a matter of whether ***in the future**, you **will** go to uni,* to a matter of whether ***at time of speaking**, your "**current** state" is that you intend/are expected to go to uni.*

Comment: But you also changed 'might' to 'must'

Comment: I thought that might (must?! :) make things easier to understand. I could rephrase #1 to *If you go to university, you **must** learn quantum electrodynamics*. As in *If you get your girlfriend pregnant, you must marry her*, which is obviously not at all the same thing as *If you **are to** get your girlfriend pregnant, you must have sex with her*).